# Using generalized hypergeometrics in RegionPlot hangs the Kernel

Tags: plotting, special-functions, kernel

This simple code, is just an example, hangs the kernel:

```
RegionPlot[
 x + y + HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 2.5, 3.1}, {4.65, 3.28}, 0.2] > 
  0, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -2, 3}]
```

In reality, I want to use a more complicated function involving generalized hypergeomectrics and its derivatives in the inequality defining the region, (where the parameters are the ones defining the region). And that hangs the kernel when using RegionPlot.
But then, I realize that the problem was just when using generalized hypergeometrics inside RegionPlot, even if it is just a constant, in this case:

```
In[1]:= HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 2.5, 3.1}, {4.65, 3.28}, 0.2]

Out[1]= 1.11552
```

So there is even no variable inside the hypergeometric fucntion, it is just a number.

why is this happening? it seems to be a bug...

Any idea to bypass this problem?
Remember that in the real code i want to use generalized hyoergeometrics and derivatives where the variables defining the regions are in the parameters.
something more like:

```
RegionPlot[
 x - HypergeometricPFQ[{y, 2.5, 3.1}, {4.65, 3.28}, 0.2] > 
  0, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -2, 3}]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: With v12.3.1 on a Mac, each plots evaluates in less than a second. Try restarting your Mathematica.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GVWr.png

Comment: thanks to both!! indeed it was a bug in the version 12.0.0 that i had. Now I updated to version 12.3.1 and now is working without problems as expected